# How to generate url to add event to Outlook Web Client calendar

Tags: outlook, calendar

On my website, I want to have a link "Add to calendar". It works perfectly with Outlook.com but not for users using Outlook Web Client.

This is my Outlook.com url (works great):

```
https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/calendar/action/compose&rru=addevent&startdt=2018-05-24T12%3A00%3A00-05%3A00&enddt=2018-05-24T12%3A30%3A00-05%3A00&subject=Test%One%&body=Test%Body
```

These are urls I tried with the Outlook Web Client (don't work):

```
https://yourexchangeserveraddr/owa?path=/calendar/action/compose&rru=addevent&startdt=2018-05-24T12%3A00%3A00-05%3A00&enddt=2018-05-24T12%3A30%3A00-05%3A00&subject=Test%One%&body=Test%Body
https://yourexchangeserveraddr/owa?cmd=contents&module=calendar&path=/calendar/action/compose&rru=addevent&startdt=2018-05-24T12%3A00%3A00-05%3A00&enddt=2018-05-24T12%3A30%3A00-05%3A00&subject=Test%One%&body=Test%Body
https://yourexchangeserveraddr/owa?cmd=contents&module=calendar&rru=addevent&startdt=2018-05-24T12%3A00%3A00-05%3A00&enddt=2018-05-24T12%3A30%3A00-05%3A00&subject=Test%One%&body=Test%Body
```

Comment: Your first URL helped me, there's not much information on how to create an event through a URL to Outlook.

Comment: Your first url works for me. Thanks for the url.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this ? I need to do the same

Comment: No I never did. I feel like it just isn’t possible.

Comment: Can you explain what domain you use for Outlook Web Client?  Pretty sure "yourexchangeserveradd" is not a real domain.

Comment: @RaymondNaseef I used that as an example. You would use use your exchange server's url.

Comment: The first URL is not working for me. Did they remove this feature?

Comment: First url is not working but this is a kind of alternative `https://outlook.live.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose`. First url works for office365 though.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your proposal and the first answer, here my working solution, be carreful with datetime format for start and end parameter:

```
https://outlook.office.com/owa/?path=/calendar/action/compose&rru=addevent&startdt=2021-05-24T12%3A00%3A00-05%3A00&enddt=2021-05-25T12%3A00%3A00-05%3A00&subject=Test&location=Attineos&body=blabla
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work any more ?

Comment: This works for me. Thank you! Here is the sample link for all day event. 'https://outlook.office.com/owa/?path=/calendar/action/compose&rru=addevent&startdt=2023-07-31&enddt=2023-08-01&allday=true&subject=Celebration&location=Jorvee&body=This_Monday_we_are_celebrating'

Answer (score 0):

Following used to work for us

https://outlook.office.com/owa/?path=/calendar/view/Month&subject=Event&startdt=20200608&enddt=20200615&allday=true&location=TBD&body=Author%3a%0aAshish+Narang+(+ashish%40simpplr.com)%0a%0aSummary%3a%0aMy+Event%0a%0ahttps%3a%2f%2fpira-dev-ed--c.visualforce.com%2fapex%2fSiteEventsDetail%3fcontentId%3da0G4N00000bW6LZUA0%26siteId%3da074N00000sAHEzQAO&uid=1584589379044%40simpplr.com

Comment: doesnt seem to work any more :(

Comment: Just got this link, probably useful for others https://www.labnol.org/apps/calendar.html

Comment: This doesnt work for me either

Comment: Here is updated URL format https://outlook.live.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose?rru=addevent&subject=test+event&startdt=2021-03-16T20:45:00Z&enddt=2021-03-16T21:15:00Z&allday=false&location=zoom&body=Author%3A%0AXYZ+ABC+%28+XYZ40mydomain.com%29%0A%0ASummary%3A%0Atest%0A%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fgoodco--simpplr.vf.force.com%2Fapex%2Fsimpplr__app%3Fu%3D%2Fsite%2Fa0No000000EEsYjEAL%2Fevent%2Fa0H3l00000S7DvIEAV&uid=1639496924604@mydomain.com&path=/calendar/action/compose

Comment: I get an error from outlook.live.com for that : including 'X-Auth-Error System.ArgumentException'

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Office / Microsoft 365 (mostly work emails): https://outlook.office.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose?allday=false&body=Nice%20description&enddt=2022-10-25T21%3A45%3A00%2B00%3A00&location=Event&path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addevent&startdt=2022-10-25T21%3A15%3A00%2B00%3A00&subject=Test%20Meeting

Outlook for Web (private accounts mostly): https://outlook.live.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose?allday=false&body=Nice%20description&enddt=2022-10-25T21%3A45%3A00%2B00%3A00&location=Event&path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addevent&startdt=2022-10-25T21%3A15%3A00%2B00%3A00&subject=Test%20Meeting

Seems you can also add attendees:

`&to=email@example.org,email2@example.org`

`&cc=email@example.org,email2@example.org`

I don't know if all this works for Exchange/OWA.

Thanks for this link to test parameters @Ashish https://www.labnol.org/apps/calendar.html